# How to change the shape of Navigation tab?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to build navigation bar like this using BootStrap:

[image: Navigation]

How should I style it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: You should tell what u have done before. You can't ask for source code without some effort / share code you have wrote.

Comment: If I were you, I will use background images & CSS to achieve your goal. Use pure CSS like `transform` may probably lead to browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Unless you need to support very old browser versions then css transform should be fine.  There a numerous examples of people using pure css to achieve this effect without browser compatibility issues.  e.g.http://lea.verou.me/2013/10/slanted-tabs-with-css-3d-transforms/

Answer (score 0):

Using border-radius, and transform: skew(---) you should be able to achieve the desired effect.